# how to drop base64 img string

Tags: javascript, php, summernote

I'm pulling a content from a table using php with several text including a base64 img string, i would like to drop or remove the base64 string.

By the way, the text and base64 img is coming from summernote wysiwyg editor.

hope you can help me about this. thanks in advance.

```
<p>several text here </p>
<p>several text again here </p>
<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAQ4CAYAAADo08FDAAAgAElEQVR4AeydCXxU1dn/f5M9IQvLANnYt6BCIhI3xC1xC1WwUAvVgvJi3742L69ibRH/1XQD1AKWptYqBaFakYriQkRNBAQKGM==" data-filename="image.png" style="width: 1078px;"><br></p>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to end up with? What is "the desired text"?

Comment: We need more details

Comment: If you want to extract text from a bitmap image, you need a library to do that, something similar to optical character readers (OCR).

Comment: What do you mean by "desired text"?

Comment: i just want to drop or remove the <p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAQ4CAYAAADo08FDAAAgAElEQVR4AeydCXxU1dn/f5M9IQvLANnYt6BCIhI3xC1xC1WwUAvVgvJi3742L69ibRH/1XQD1AKWptYqBaFakYriQkRNBAQKGM==" data-filename="image.png" style="width: 1078px;"><br></p>, i only want the <p>several text here </p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use strip_tags().
Here I use the second parameter to allow `<p>` tag but if the actual tag is not important remove the `"<p>"` from the function.

```
$html = '<p>several text here </p>
<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAQ4CAYAAADo08FDAAAgAElEQVR4AeydCXxU1dn/f5M9IQvLANnYt6BCIhI3xC1xC1WwUAvVgvJi3742L69ibRH/1XQD1AKWptYqBaFakYriQkRNBAQKGM==" data-filename="image.png" style="width: 1078px;"><br></p>';

Echo strip_tags($html, "<p>");
```

Output:

```
<p>several text here </p>
<p></p>
```

But as I said, if it's only the text that is needed just remove the `"<p>"` and it will only echo the actual text.

If you only want the first line and with the tag you can explode on PHP_EOL and use the first item.

```
Echo explode(PHP_EOL, strip_tags($html, "<p>"))[0];
```

output:

```
<p>several text here </p>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was fast, didn't know how easy was that.

Comment: I see that you have updated your question with a second line of text. That means my explode will not work. But do you need some method of solving it? Is the picture always last?

Comment: your response is just what i need, the image does not matter